# IIS 10 - TLS 1.2 (server has no preference)

Tags: encryption, tls1.2, iis-10

I have a win 2016 server with IIS 10 and some websites. I also have a wildcard certificate (SHA-256 With RSA Encryption).
I am trying to harden the web server, disabling not secure protocols (only TLS 1.2 allowed)/ciphers and I face two problems:

1) The cipher suite list I use (used IISCrypto) is the below:

> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

If I disable the SHA1 ciphers (for more security) and the TLS_DHE ciphers for forward secrecy, my TLS breaks (error on web browsers). Why is this happening? What is the best approach on this?

2) At online ssl tests (qualys+), I get the message (at cipher suites):

## TLS 1.2 (server has no preference)

I've been looking if there is a setting somewhere to set the preference of the server but didn't find anything. Any idea on this?

Note that I have enabled the group policy (Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Network, SSL Configuration Settings => SSL Cipher Suite Order).

Comment: Your certificate is not qualified for ECDSA. You need to get a suitable one (ECC) and then try again. But note that its adoption is still in progress, https://certsimple.com/blog/ecc-https-certificate-support

Comment: Its a bit hard to give a solution with description. Please enable network monitor https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=4865 on both server and client side. Then capture SSL handshake on both side. Then you will know what Schannel configuration should be applied on your server.

Comment: ok, so all the ECDSA ciphers cannot be used, due the nature of the SSL certificate, supporting RSA instead.

Comment: For my second question, I found that happens due to my firewall which is in front and performs SSL inspection. When I bypass the relevant rule, I do not get the "server has no preference" message any more. Thanks.